# how to slice a dataframe from the end to the beginning?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, slice

I am slicing a dataframe like this:

```
for i in xrange(0,len(df),100000):
    print("slice %d!!!!" % i)
    slice= df.iloc[i:(i+100000)]
```

I would like now to get `100k` slices **from the end to the beginning** of the df (without necessarily sorting my dataframe).

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `tail`:

```
df.tail(100000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[-100000:]
```